# ELI5 Explain native assets at higher level?

Tags: nft, native-assets

Is anyone capable of providing a high-level explanation of how NFT works in Cardano from a traditional blockchain point of view (ERC721, Ethereum, Solana, NEAR, etc), as I'd be very interested in understanding enough to decide going forward with Cardano for a project?

I've read the https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts and believe that I understood a bit of it, but got a few questions.

- The Policy ID can be used to identify a collection of native assets (NFT)? E.g. I can query the blockchain and find every single native asset by Policy ID?
- The amount field* for the Policy ID has to be defined, there can't be unlimited supply?
- Policy time locking, how to determine amount of slots in terms of time? Can be average, I guess the slots are computed so depends on the blockchain usage?!
- The Policy ID signature is the mint-authority/controller/admin "wallet address"?
- Does a Policy ID allow us to set multiple signatures (mint-authorities/controller/admin)? Guess that's what the https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/c6b574229f76627a058a7e559599d2fc3f40575d/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md is for where keyHash is the wallet address and the type "sig" as in "signature"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**ELI5 for Native Assets** from a traditional blockchain point of view (ERC721, Ethereum, Solana, NEAR, etc):

Native Assets are like Pokemon cards: All the needed information and features pertaining to the asset is directly on the individual card and can be interacted with freely.

ERC-standard tokens(eg. ERC-721) are like Pokemon game cartridges for GBA: There's a minimum information available on the cartridge casing but it is completely useless unless you plug it into a GBA console. The GBA console is needed to interact with the cartridge and everything it offers. The GBA console is to the cartridge what the EVM is to ERC-standard tokens (which are not tokens but rather programs/smart contracts with balances and permissions).

***Other things***

Policy ID for Cardano Native Assets is similar to contract address for Ethereum ERC tokens

> The Policy ID can be used to identify a collection of native assets (NFT)? E.g. I can query the blockchain and find every single native asset by Policy ID?

This is how much you want to mint in a given transaction, you can mint ad infinitum so long as you execute mint transactions via Native Scripts while the Policy is open OR via Plutus scripts per the logic.

> The amount field* for the Policy ID has to be defined, there can't be unlimited supply?

A slot is currently = 1 second, isn't dependent on usage.

> Policy time locking, how to determine amount of slots in terms of time? Can be average, I guess the slots are computed so depends on the blockchain usage?!

The Policy script signature is the Verification key hash of the mint-authority/controller/admin, so not wallet address. (Wallet address is derived from a different combination of keys).

> The Policy ID signature is the mint-authority/controller/admin "wallet address"

Yes you can set multiple required signatures for a policy script.

> Does a Policy ID allow us to set multiple signatures (mint-authorities/controller/admin)?

keyHash != wallet address. it is the hash of the verification keys. and yes "sig" means "signature"

> for where keyHash is the wallet address and the type "sig" as in "signature"?